# Is there a prop available to call a function when close button (cross icon) is clicked for introjs-react step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, intro.js

I'm pretty new to `introjs-react`. I have gone through the documentation and know there are 2 props available `onExit` and `onComplete`. The previous is called when we skip a step (for example when clicking outside the step on the overlay) and the latter is called when `done` is pressed. I want to call a method when the close button (the cross icon) on the step is pressed.

This is how my current step looks like
[image: Tooltip]

Here's how my code looks like

```
<Steps
      enabled={activateDemo}
      steps={steps.map((step) => ({ ...step, tooltipClass: classes.tooltipClass }))}
      initialStep={0}
      ref={(ref) => {
        introJsRef.current = ref;
      }}
      options={{
        exitOnOverlayClick: false,
        scrollToElement: true,
        scrollTo: 'tooltip',
        disableInteraction: true,
        showButtons: true,
      }}
      onBeforeChange={(nextStepIndex) => {
        if (steps[nextStepIndex] && introJsRef.current)
          introJsRef.current!.updateStepElement(nextStepIndex);
        return true;
      }}
      onExit={onExit}
      onComplete={onComplete}
      onClose={onComplete} // <---- Does something of this sort exists??????
    />
  );
```

This is the [documention](https://github.com/HiDeoo/intro.js-react) I'm going through.
Any leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://github.com/HiDeoo/intro.js-react#user-content-props-1:%7E:text=onClose) answer your question?